# How to Identify Delegating Object

Tags: swift, delegation

I am using delegation and am using the same class in two different ways.

```
    protocol ColorSwitchDelegate {
        func colorSwitched(picker: ColorSwitch, color: ColorChoice)
    }

    class ColorSwitch: UIView {    
        var delegate: ColorSwitchDelegate?

    func doSomething() {
    delegate?.colorSwitched(picker: self, color: color)
    }
    }

    class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, ColorSwitchDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView1: ColorSwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var myView2: ColorSwitch!

    func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

     myView1.delegate = self
     myView2.delegate = self
    }



  func colorSwitched(picker: ColorSwitch, color: ColorChoice) {
            // I want to find out if myView1 or myView2 is the delegating object
    }
    }
```

I want to identify which view (myView1 or myView2) is the delegator. I could add a tag in the ColorSwitch class but this seems inelegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: you can check if picker == self.myView1 { }. but i guess adding tag is the best.

Comment: Sorry I clarified my code. Both myView1 and myView2 have the delegate set to the SettingsViewController. So I can't check for nil.

Comment: `if picker === myView1 { // do something with 1 } else if picker === myView2 { // do something with 2 }`

Comment: Awesome, both of your solutions work, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly check  in `colorSwitched` using identity opeartor === which test whether two object references both refer to the same object instance.

```
func colorSwitched(picker: ColorSwitch, color: ColorChoice) {
   if picker === self.myView1 { 

     //myView1
    } else {

     //myView2

    } 

}
```